# Is there http health monitoring in crate?

Tags: health-monitoring, crate

is there an interface in crate like there is in ES - like this one /_cluster/health?pretty=true

I know i can enable the ES one, just wondering if there was one more specific to crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin-ui that is included in Crate uses some SQL queries to determine the health. That's explained in [this issue on github](https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/1396). Other than that there is no interface to do that. (Other than using the ES API as you mentioned)